# shell printf in color variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
diskusage=$(df "/" | grep / | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' | sed 's/%//g')

    if [ "$diskusage" -ge 85 ];then
        echo "-------------->  Warning Disk usage "${s[@]}"  $diskusage% is Above Threshold  "
             disk_color='\e[1;31m%-6s\e[m'
         #red color

    else
             disk_color='\e[1;32m%-6s\e[m'
             #green color                             

    fi


 printf -v spaces '%*s' 100 ''; printf '%s\n' ${spaces// /_}
 printf -v spaces '%*s' $diskusage ''; printf '%s\n' ${spaces// /▇}"  $diskusage% Used "
 printf -v spaces '%*s' 100 ''; printf '%s\n' ${spaces// /-}
```

the output is ok as expected but it's not printing "/▇" in color:

```
▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 8% Used ------------------------------------------------------------‌​--------------------‌​--------------------
```

Comment: the output is ok as expected but it's not printing "/▇"  in color

Comment: ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇  8% Used
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: The `disk_color` you define is supposed to be used as a printf format but you don't actually use it when printing.

Comment: Don't use `\e[1;31m`.  Instead, write `$(tput setaf 1)`.  It's much cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `disk_color` to be inside the format string for this to work, so:

```
printf "This is a regular string, but $disk_color\n" "This is a green string"
```

Now the green string can be properly formatted.`%-6s` is the part of taking the argument and embedding it in the printed string, and it needs to be in the format string (first argument).